# Controlling bg and fg in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data that I am trying to plot.
I would like the fill (bg) to be controlled by a logical variable.
The only way I can make it work is by layering two sets of points.

Is there a better way?

```
require(ggplot2)

dat<-data.frame(
  x=rep(1:10, 2),
  val=c(rnorm(10, 10), rnorm(10, 12)),
  grp=rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
  tf=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 20, replace=TRUE)
  )

ggplot(dat, aes(x, val, col=grp))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(alpha=tf), size=4)+
  geom_point(shape=21, size=4, aes(fg=grp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a manual shape to do this.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, val, col=grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=tf), size=4) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,21))
```

Comment: Love it - that's brilliant thinking. Thanks